# oci_fetch_array no me deja imprimir todo el arreglo completo

Tags: php, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE seleccionar (
    registros  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    codigo     NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN registros FOR SELECT
                           imagen,
                           nombre_producto,
                           precio_producto
                       FROM
                           producto
                       WHERE
                           id_categoria = codigo;
END;
```

Ese es mi proceso almacenado

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('ProyectoLBD', 'ProyectoLBD', 'orcl');
$sql = 'BEGIN seleccionar(:registros,:codigo); END;';     
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);     
$paramIn = 1;
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":codigo",$paramIn,-1,SQLT_INT);     
$rs = oci_new_cursor($conn);     
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":registros",$rs,-1,OCI_B_CURSOR);    
oci_execute($stmt);    
oci_execute($rs);    
$mData=array();     
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($rs)) {   
   $mData[] = $row;   
}    
 var_dump($mData);
echo json_encode($mData);
?>
```

> Si lo imprimo de esa manera el formato `json` no funciona y si lo
> imprimo fuera de `while` lo único que imprime es un FALSE.
> El echo `json_encode($mData);` si imprime el arry pero el `json_encode` no imprime nada en absoluto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el apartado **Stored Procedures and Reference Cursors** de la [documentación de Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/fuecks-sps.html):

> To work with a cursor in PHP two additional steps are required, as
> compared to accessing rows directly from a SELECT statement. The first
> step is preparing a cursor resource in PHP, using the oci_new_cursor()
> function, which you then use to bind to the appropriate parameter. The
> second step, after you have executed the SQL statement, is calling
> oci_execute() on the cursor resource.
>
> ---
>
> Para trabajar con un cursor en PHP se requieren dos pasos adicionales,
> en comparación con acceder a las filas directamente desde una
> instrucción `SELECT`. El primer paso es preparar un recurso de cursor
> en PHP, usando la función [`oci_new_cursor()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-new-cursor.php), que luego se usa
> para enlazar al parámetro apropiado. El segundo paso, después de haber
> ejecutado la instrucción SQL, es llamar a [`oci_execute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php) en el
> recurso del cursor.

Tu código debería funcionar de este modo, salvo otros errores:

```
$conn = oci_connect('ProyectoLBD', 'ProyectoLBD', 'orcl');
$sql = 'BEGIN seleccionar(:registros,:codigo); END;'; 

#Suele usarse $stmt como convención de nombre  
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
 
// Bind del parámetro de entrada :codigo usando la variable $paramIn 
$paramIn = 1;
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":codigo",$paramIn,-1,SQLT_INT);
 
// Crear un recurso que será el que leeremos con los resultados
$rs = oci_new_cursor($conn);
 
// Bind de $rs al argumento out de la SP Oracle 
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":registros",$rs,-1,OCI_B_CURSOR);
 
// Ejecutar el statement
oci_execute($stmt);
 
// Ejecutar el cursor
oci_execute($rs);

// Array para recoger cada fila
$mData=array();
 
// Leer los datos, no hay que complicarse usando !=false
// Y se puede usar un método más específico como oci_fetch_assoc
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($rs)) {   
   $mData[] = $row;   
}

 #Para debug, quitarlo cuando funcione
 var_dump($mData);

// Imprimir fuera del while
echo json_encode($mData);
```

Si te dice que el JSON no es válido, copia y pega la salida y evalúala en [este validador](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), así podrás saber qué problema hay en tu json.

Comment: Al hacer ese cambio se presenta el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: oci_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 argument, 2 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoBD\AgregarTarjetas.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoBD\AgregarTarjetas.php(26): oci_fetch_assoc(Resource id #4, 4) #1

Comment: @user15606804 Prueba así: `while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($rs)) {`

Comment: Actualmente ya esta imprimiendo la información, pero no se si es por mi desconocimiento o un error de novato que al copiar esa información y verificar si es un JSON en una pagina que verifica el formato JSON me da múltiples errores, incluso al descomponer esa información en JavaScript con JSON.parse da error

Comment: Si quieres un JSON tienes que crear un array, irlo llenando dentro del while y luego hacer echo de ese array convirtiéndolo a JSON. Ahora edito.

Comment: @user15606804 revisa la respuesta editada. Se crea un array `$mData` que se va llenando dentro del `while` y se imprime fuera del `while`. Si el JSON no valida puede ser por otro motivo, como problemas de codificación en los datos o que se agregan más cosas al flujo de salida...

Comment: Hice los cambios pero ahora no imprime nada.

Comment: Olvidé quitar el error del while. Ahora edito.

Comment: Revisa ahora editado. Debería funciona así. Si no funciona edita la pregunta poniendo al final la nueva versión del código. Puede que se te haya escapado algo.

Comment: El   var_dump($mData); si esta imprimiendo el array pero el echo json_encode($mData); no esta imprimiendo nada.

Comment: @user15606804 puede que el json no sea válido y por eso no está funcionando el `json_encode`. Habría que ver lo que sale en el `var_dump($mData);`, si hay caracteres extraños o algo que estarían rompiendo el json.

Comment: Ya descubrí cuales eran los caracteres que hacia fallar el json_encode, muchas gracias por la ayuda.